# Como verificar se dois vetores tem valores iguais de forma rápida

Tags: c, array

O numero de elemento chegam a 100000 e tenho que comparar com outro vetor de 100000, como eu posso fazer isso com um ganho de desemprenho muito alto

Forma como estou comparando os vetores

```
for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < teste; j++)
    {
        if(indice[i] == aux[j])
        {
            cont++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Para teu cenário esse modo recursivo é o recomendado, já que você precisa verificar cada valor; caso pretenda apenas comparar se os vetores são iguais, pode usar strcmp.

Comment: olá Mauro, o vetor são de números, então não vai da pra utilizar o strcmp, você poderia me dar um exemplo de como seria esse modo recursivo ?, obrigado desde já

Comment: Tem os valores iguais de que forma ? tem os mesmos numeros nas mesmas posições ? Ou os mesmos numeros mesmo que em posições diferentes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar criar um vetor *hash*, por exemplo

```
char hash[0x7FFFFFFF];
```

se forem possíveis quaisquer números inteiros positivos.

Inicialize o vetor,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 0x7FFFFFFF; ++i)
{
    hash[i] = 0;
}
```

Itere um dos seus vetores originais e use o *hash* para saber que aquele número existe neste vetor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < teste; ++i)
{
    hash[indice[i]] = 1;
}
```

Daí itere o segundo vetor, incrementando `cont` caso o *hash* já esteja preenchido,

```
for (int i = 0; i < teste; ++i)
{
    if (hash[aux[i]])
    {
        ++cont;
    }
}
```

Dessa forma a complexidade passa a ser O(n), em vez de O(n^2), que era teu caso.

O problema, agora, é que é usada muita memória RAM. 1 GB de RAM, no mínimo, só para o vetor *hash*...

Então existe uma contrapartida entre complexidade algorítmica e complexidade espacial, que deve ser sempre levada em consideração.

Comment: Acho legal citar os métodos de busca/ordenação também! Podem ser úteis para aprendizagem (por exemplo, este algoritmo usado na pergunta seria um "Bubble Sort".. introduzir um "Shell Sort" ou "Selection Sort" para o Rafael estudar ia bem!)

Comment: Obrigado marcelo funcionou

Comment: Vou pesquisar Cleber, obrigado pela dica

Answer (score -1):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int vet[3] = {2, 5, 7};
int var[3] = {2, 5, 5};

void verifica(int valor, int posicao){
    if(valor == vet[posicao]){
        printf("%d = %d\n",valor, vet[posicao]);
    }else{
        printf("[%d] != [%d] Não é igual !",valor, vet[posicao]);
    }
}

int main(){
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        verifica(var[i], i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT**: Não tinha visto os comentários do post inicial. Pensei que a intenção era verificar a igualdade de dois vetores (em um sentido mais matemático). Aparentemente, deseja-se tratar uma array como um conjunto de elementos (repetidos ou não), e verificar se eles possuem os mesmos elementos. Sendo assim, esta solução não funcionará.

---

Se a intenção é apenas verificar se dois vetores são iguais, **E** considerando que estes sejam de mesmo tamanho, você pode talvez utilizar o [memcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp):

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* memcmp é declarado nesta lib */
#include <string.h>

int vet1[] = {0, 1, 3};
int vet2[] = {0, 1, 2};

int main() {
  /* Note que esta comparação só é válida pois:
   * 1. Ambos os vetores possuem o mesmo tamanho (3 elementos); E
   * 2. Ambos os vetores possuem o mesmo tipo de elemento (int).
   */
  if (memcmp(&vet1, &vet2, sizeof vet1) == 0) {
    printf("iguais\n");
  } else {
    printf("diferentes\n");
  }
}
```

Pastebin (executável): https://glot.io/snippets/g44yb5qaoh

Isto só funciona se os dois vetores possuírem o mesmo layout em memória, o que é o caso. Sendo assim, eles podem ser comparados byte a byte, ao invés de elemento a elemento.

Em alguns casos, `memcmp` é uma melhor opção do que um simples loop, já que a maioria dos toolchains otimizam-o via [SIMD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) ou funcionalidade semelhante a nível de hardware. Vide:

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106801/why-is-memcmp-so-much-faster-than-a-for-loop-check#:~:text=Highly%2Doptimized%20versions%20of%20memcmp,lots%20of%20data%20in%20parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106801/why-is-memcmp-so-much-faster-than-a-for-loop-check#:%7E:text=Highly%2Doptimized%20versions%20of%20memcmp,lots%20of%20data%20in%20parallel).

Caso não haja uma otimização disponível, dada a simples assinatura do `memcmp`, não deve ser difícil implementar esta função usando [*compiler intrinsics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) [1]. No seu caso, especificamente (decidir se um vetor é igual ao outro), pode-se simplificar a definição da função para contemplar apenas igualdade (i.e. remover do retorno da função a necessidade de efetuar o cálculo da diferença entre os primeiros bytes que diferem nos dois vetores).

---

[1] Vide também: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html

Comment: Ele não que ver se dois vetores são idênticos. Quer saber se dois vetores de mesmo comprimento possuem os mesmos elementos independente da ordem que se encontrem. No caso seria necessário ordenar os dois vetores antes de usar a função `memcmp()`.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AugustoVasques isso não ficou claro no enunciado. O que você descreve é mais similar a conjuntos. Ele falou sobre comparação de vetores, e não sobre comparação de conjuntos.

Comment: @FlávioLisbôa, você está equivocado. Na pergunta, aquela estrutura de comparação envolvendo laços aninhados é a contração dos algoritmos de comparação como o algoritmo de ordenação bubble sort.

Comment: @AugustoVasques agora li os comentários do post inicial, e percebi o que o autor realmente quis perguntar. Editei a resposta para indicar que ela não funcionará para o que foi pedido. Obrigado pela revisão.

Comment: Você ainda pode editar sua resposta e implementar um algoritmo que seja eficiente para solucionar o problema do AP.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Acho que a resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/303077/185737 é a mais adequada, em geral. Mas há a oportunidade de, talvez, adaptar um algoritmo de busca para fazer esta comparação, também (dependendo das condições iniciais dos dois vetores). Em geral, acho que ele poderia estar usando um tipo de dado abstrato mais adequado ao problema que ele está tentando resolver...

Comment: Assim que tiver tempo, posso fazer uma nova resposta. Que a minha falta de atenção fique aqui visível à todos, para que ninguém mais caia no erro de sugerir memcmp! :D

Comment: Entendo sua posição e concordo com a análise. Mas não queria o ver recebendo negativo nessa resposta. No caso você pode remover a resposta, os negativos serão revertidos, e somente os usuários com mais de 10.000 pontos de reputação poderão ver. Fora o fato é possível usar o memcmp mas para isso os vetores devem ser ordenados previamente, o aumenta a complexidade de tempo.